# How can I save my VS solution in a separate repo from its projects?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfs-2015

Ulitmately, I want to avoid having to create multiple solutions since all of the projects are for the same solution.

For instance, if I have a visual studio solution for website "MyWebsite" and want to create a "MyWebsite.UI" project and a "MyWebsite.Services" project that all lived in separate repos, how can I do this via Visual Studio / TFS?

- MyWebsite Solution (repo 1)

  - MyWebsite.UI Project (repo 2)
  - MyWebsite.Services Project (repo 3)

The bigger picture that I am trying to achieve is being able to focus either individual projects or the entire solution.  However, if I clone a repo for one of the projects, it will be lacking a solution.  If I clone the solution, it will have all of the projects.

I am using Visual Studio Team Foundation Services with git version control.

Comment: Why not have one source code repository for the 2 projects but have multiple solutions in the folder.   This way you could open the solution that only has the projects you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you wan't to have them in different repositories? It's perfectly fine to have a solution containing multiple projects, or different solutions containing different projects.

For splitting can use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) in the Git repository containing the solution to add the repositories containing the projects. In this case you need to make sure that you pull the submodules while cloning the repository.

Another solution to reuse common libraries in different solutions is to package them as NuGet packages and host them on a private feed.